# How to use custom javascript alert boxes (like SweetAlert) when creating Chrome Extensions?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, web, alert

I am creating my first Chrome extension and am having a difficult time integrating SweetAlert. I would like to automatically have a custom alert pop up at every single page, and I have tried several different ways. With SweetAlert, I keep getting "swal not defined." I tried loading HTML from alert.html, which then imports in SweetAlert.min.js and its CSS file, into contentscript.js, with no avail. 
I also tried using Alert.render(). Here is the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#dialogoverlay{
    display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    border-radius:7px; 
    width:550px;
    z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ background:#FFF; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #666; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#CCC; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ background:#333; padding:20px; color:#FFF; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ background: #666; padding:10px; text-align:right; }
</style>
<script>
function CustomAlert(){
    this.render = function(dialog){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
        var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
        dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
        dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
        dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
        dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
        dialogbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Acknowledge This Message";
        document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
        document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()">OK</button>';
    }
    this.ok = function(){
        document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
<div id="dialogbox">
  <div>
    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in my "contentscript.js", I have the following:
     Alert.render("Is this working?") 
Then I tried appending the html to an element in the web page, but that didn't work either (it kept giving me a "denied access..load into web_access_resources", which I had already done for ALert.html
Anyone have any ideas? 
Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you managed to run SweetAlert using content script at all (without custom alert boxes)? I suppose not if you are getting "swal" is undefined.

You need to define your content script in **manifest.json**,

```
  "content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://www.chosen-regex-pattern.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.min.js", "sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js", "contentscript.js"],
    "css": ["sweetalert/sweetalert.css"]
  }
```

It is also **important that you write jQuery & Sweetalert libraries before contentscript.js**. It might be why you are getting swal() or sweetAlert() undefined as the code in contentscript.js runs earlier than the libraries are imported.

And as for me it works without it, but I suppose you might need whitelist your files in Web Accessible Resouces as:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
   "http://somewhere.com/jquery.min.js",
   "sweetalert/sweetalert.*"
    ]
```

> For example, an extension that injects a content script with the
>   intention of building up some custom interface for example.com would
>   whitelist any resources that interface requires (images, icons,
>   stylesheets, scripts, etc.) as follows...
>   [Chrome Extension Manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)

After all of this at least this line in contentscript.js should work well:

```
sweetAlert("Well...", "It's finally working!", "success");
```